# Plotting multiple scatter plots with simple linear regression equation showing in python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a pandas df with multiple columns. I want to scatter plot multiple ordinary least squares regressions with equations showing on the plot. I also want to vary based on another column or 'hue' so that certain column values or hue's are plotted separately.

```
sns.relplot(y='Latitude', x='Longitude', hue='cluster', palette="Paired", s=9, data=df)
```

[image: This is what I currently have: note that it does not have regression equation.]

Is there a streamlined way of doing this, so that you don't have to write a function to iterate over each column and hue?

Comment: I guess the short answer is "no". It doesn't seem too hard to do that with a `groupby` on the dataframe and plotting each required regression line separately though.